# tomcat 6 . How does HttpServletResponse make browsers react immediately , not have done response.getOutputStream().close()??

Tags: file-io, browser, tomcat6, servlets

This is the code in my servlet:

```java
while( bytes....){//do read file to bytes
    response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
    response.getOutputStream().flush();
    log4j.debug(response.isCommitted());  // out  true.
}
```

If my file is 100MB , the server must read 100MB to memory and then the browser alerts
a dialog of downloading file.
How the waiting time of the browser  terrible, when my file is gt than 2GB ....

Answer (score 1):

Browser compatibility problems, from Servlet Best Practices, Part 3  by The O'Reilly Java Authors:

> The bad news is that although the HTTP specification provides a
>   mechanism  for file downloads (see HTTP/1.1, Section 19.5.1),  many
>   browsers second-guess the server's directives and do what they think
>   is best  rather than what they're told.
>
> The good news is that the right combination of headers will download
>   files well enough  to be practical. With these special headers set, a
>   compliant browser will open a Save As dialog,  while a noncompliant
>   browser will open the dialog for all content except HTML or image
>   files.
>
> set the `Content-Type` header to a nonstandard value such as
>   `application/x-download`.